# batch download from camscanner

Tags: mobile-phone, document-scanning

Is there a way to bulk-download from the Camscanner mobile app? I've got lots of docs in Camscanner cloud there that I would like to retrieve, but I cannot find a way to download them all except for downloading them one by one which would be impractical. Any ideas?
Thanks,
Avsha.

Comment: Did you try anything? Why is this tagged mobile-phone? What kind of service it it? What access options exist?

Comment: Camscanner is a mobile app for Android and Iphone that allows you to scan documents with the phone camera, it comes with its own cloud service, which you can log into from Windows as well. I basically went over all options of the Android and Windows GUI, could not find how to bulk download. This should be tagged "camscanner" but I don't have enough points to create a new tag as it seems.

Comment: Adding an independent tag for it would probably be too much but it's unclear what you're actually looking at. With the information you have provided its also likely [off-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) because you're working an android app and a webservice. As its likely a limitation on their end I'd try to contact the support/check the documentation. A work around could be to sync them to your phone and attach the phone to your PC.